# How to mount ZTE ZXHN H267N share with samba in Linux?

Tags: linux, router, mount, samba

I've been given a `ZTE ZXHN H267N` router that allows exporting a connected USB storage device as a samba share.

As you can see in the screenshot below, there are not much configuration options, and it's pretty straightforward.

[image: samba configuration]

From Windows I can open the share by simply accessing `\\192.168.1.1`: I can browse it, read files, write/copy files into it... so everything seems to work as expected.

But from Linux I'm unable to mount it in read-write mode. I actually can mount it, but I cannot read nor write anything. I have tried any logic combination of mount options to no avail.

```
root@host:/tmp# mount --verbose -t cifs -o rw,guest,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 //192.168.1.1/samba ./asd
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.1.1,unc=\\192.168.1.1\samba,guest,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,user=,prefixpath=,pass=********
root@host:/tmp# cd asd
root@host:/tmp/asd# LANG=C touch a
touch: cannot touch `a': Permission denied
root@host:/tmp/asd#
```

In the example above, the share is mounted, and `a` doesn't exist. Also, if I run `lsattr` on a file that already exists, I get the following:

```
root@host:/tmp/asd# LANG=C lsattr existingfile
lsattr: Permission denied While reading flags on existingfile
```

Seemingly I have no read nor write permissions. I have tried other options like:

- Specifying `uid` and `gid`, from `1` to `10000`.
- Specifying `sec` to any available option.
- Specifying `user` to a local user.
- Setting a user and a password and trying to mount it not as `guest`, but specifying `username` and `password` instead.
- Some other options and combinations of the above.

I can't figure out what other options should be specified to mount this share as `rw`. Router's documentation says nothing about which options should be specified to correctly mount it.

Has anyone managed to mount a share from this or a similar router as R/W?

Any tips are welcome as well.

**--- EDIT 1 ---**

As of `@gmelis`'s suggestions, I've put a `tcpdump` listener on the machine to just before mounting to see what's happening. The filter I've tried was: `-i eth0 -n host 192.168.1.1`, and the result is:

```
17:19:54.175169 IP 192.168.1.200.40703 > 192.168.1.1.445: Flags [S], seq 1716673820, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 45819160 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
17:19:54.182221 IP 192.168.1.1.445 > 192.168.1.200.40703: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1716673821, win 0, length 0
17:19:54.186283 IP 192.168.1.200.42696 > 192.168.1.1.139: Flags [S], seq 170856558, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 45819161 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
17:19:54.194053 IP 192.168.1.1.139 > 192.168.1.200.42696: Flags [S.], seq 2811302286, ack 170856559, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 50456624 ecr 45819161,nop,wscale 3], length 0
17:19:54.194931 IP 192.168.1.200.42696 > 192.168.1.1.139: Flags [.], ack 1, win 457, options [nop,nop,TS val 45819162 ecr 50456624], length 0
17:19:54.196654 IP 192.168.1.200.42696 > 192.168.1.1.139: Flags [P.], seq 1:73, ack 1, win 457, options [nop,nop,TS val 45819162 ecr 50456624], length 72 NBT Session Packet: Session Request
17:19:54.202629 IP 192.168.1.1.139 > 192.168.1.200.42696: Flags [.], ack 73, win 1810, options [nop,nop,TS val 50456625 ecr 45819162], length 0
17:19:54.202992 IP 192.168.1.200.42696 > 192.168.1.1.139: Flags [P.], seq 73:155, ack 1, win 457, options [nop,nop,TS val 45819163 ecr 50456625], length 82 NBT Session Packet: Session Message
17:19:54.209332 IP 192.168.1.1.139 > 192.168.1.200.42696: Flags [.], ack 155, win 1810, options [nop,nop,TS val 50456626 ecr 45819163], length 0
17:19:54.209336 IP 192.168.1.1.139 > 192.168.1.200.42696: Flags [P.], seq 1:5, ack 155, win 1810, options [nop,nop,TS val 50456626 ecr 45819163], length 4 NBT Session Packet: Session Granted
17:19:54.212933 IP 192.168.1.200.42696 > 192.168.1.1.139: Flags [.], ack 5, win 457, options [nop,nop,TS val 45819164 ecr 50456626], length 0
17:19:54.217108 IP 192.168.1.1.139 > 192.168.1.200.42696: Flags [P.], seq 5:86, ack 155, win 1810, options [nop,nop,TS val 50456627 ecr 45819164], length 81 NBT Session Packet: Session Message
17:19:54.219993 IP 192.168.1.200.42696 > 192.168.1.1.139: Flags [.], ack 86, win 457, options [nop,nop,TS val 45819165 ecr 50456627], length 0
17:19:54.220637 IP 192.168.1.200.42696 > 192.168.1.1.139: Flags [P.], seq 155:409, ack 86, win 457, options [nop,nop,TS val 45819165 ecr 50456627], length 254 NBT Session Packet: Session Message
17:19:54.231137 IP 192.168.1.1.139 > 192.168.1.200.42696: Flags [P.], seq 86:162, ack 409, win 1944, options [nop,nop,TS val 50456628 ecr 45819165], length 76 NBT Session Packet: Session Message
17:19:54.232949 IP 192.168.1.200.42696 > 192.168.1.1.139: Flags [P.], seq 409:527, ack 162, win 457, options [nop,nop,TS val 45819166 ecr 50456628], length 118 NBT Session Packet: Session Message
17:19:54.259669 IP 192.168.1.1.139 > 192.168.1.200.42696: Flags [P.], seq 162:213, ack 527, win 1944, options [nop,nop,TS val 50456631 ecr 45819166], length 51 NBT Session Packet: Session Message
17:19:54.260757 IP 192.168.1.200.42696 > 192.168.1.1.139: Flags [P.], seq 527:599, ack 213, win 457, options [nop,nop,TS val 45819169 ecr 50456631], length 72 NBT Session Packet: Session Message
17:19:54.267619 IP 192.168.1.1.139 > 192.168.1.200.42696: Flags [P.], seq 213:281, ack 599, win 1944, options [nop,nop,TS val 50456632 ecr 45819169], length 68 NBT Session Packet: Session Message
17:19:54.268189 IP 192.168.1.200.42696 > 192.168.1.1.139: Flags [P.], seq 599:671, ack 281, win 457, options [nop,nop,TS val 45819169 ecr 50456632], length 72 NBT Session Packet: Session Message
17:19:54.273042 IP 192.168.1.1.139 > 192.168.1.200.42696: Flags [P.], seq 281:363, ack 671, win 1944, options [nop,nop,TS val 50456632 ecr 45819169], length 82 NBT Session Packet: Session Message
17:19:54.273609 IP 192.168.1.200.42696 > 192.168.1.1.139: Flags [P.], seq 671:763, ack 363, win 457, options [nop,nop,TS val 45819170 ecr 50456632], length 92 NBT Session Packet: Session Message
17:19:54.277267 IP 192.168.1.1.139 > 192.168.1.200.42696: Flags [P.], seq 363:402, ack 763, win 1944, options [nop,nop,TS val 50456633 ecr 45819170], length 39 NBT Session Packet: Session Message
17:19:54.278342 IP 192.168.1.200.42696 > 192.168.1.1.139: Flags [P.], seq 763:841, ack 402, win 457, options [nop,nop,TS val 45819170 ecr 50456633], length 78 NBT Session Packet: Session Message
17:19:54.282561 IP 192.168.1.1.139 > 192.168.1.200.42696: Flags [P.], seq 402:565, ack 841, win 1944, options [nop,nop,TS val 50456633 ecr 45819170], length 163 NBT Session Packet: Session Message
17:19:54.283691 IP 192.168.1.200.42696 > 192.168.1.1.139: Flags [P.], seq 841:919, ack 565, win 473, options [nop,nop,TS val 45819171 ecr 50456633], length 78 NBT Session Packet: Session Message
17:19:54.287372 IP 192.168.1.1.139 > 192.168.1.200.42696: Flags [P.], seq 565:728, ack 919, win 1944, options [nop,nop,TS val 50456634 ecr 45819171], length 163 NBT Session Packet: Session Message
17:19:54.287949 IP 192.168.1.200.42696 > 192.168.1.1.139: Flags [P.], seq 919:997, ack 728, win 490, options [nop,nop,TS val 45819171 ecr 50456634], length 78 NBT Session Packet: Session Message
17:19:54.292238 IP 192.168.1.1.139 > 192.168.1.200.42696: Flags [P.], seq 728:830, ack 997, win 1944, options [nop,nop,TS val 50456634 ecr 45819171], length 102 NBT Session Packet: Session Message
17:19:54.329627 IP 192.168.1.200.42696 > 192.168.1.1.139: Flags [.], ack 830, win 490, options [nop,nop,TS val 45819176 ecr 50456634], length 0
```

From that output I conclude there's an initial try to establish a connection on the `445` port which is reset by the remote host, then next tried port is `139` which seems to succeed.

I also managed to run a `ngrep` command with an equivalent filter and the result is:

```
#
G 192.168.1.1 -> 224.0.0.1 17:100
  ..................                                                                                                                                                  
##
T 192.168.1.1:445 -> 192.168.1.200:40822 [AR]
  ......                                                                                                                                                              
####
T 192.168.1.200:42815 -> 192.168.1.1:139 [AP]
  ...D CKFDENECFDEFFCFGEFFCCACACACACACA. FCFAEJCOEEEFFGEFEMFDCOEFFDCACAAA.                                                                                            
##
T 192.168.1.200:42815 -> 192.168.1.1:139 [AP]
  ...N.SMBr......................~.....+..LM1.2X002..LANMAN2.1..NT LM 0.12..POSIX 2.                                                                                  
##
T 192.168.1.1:139 -> 192.168.1.200:42815 [AP]
  ....                                                                                                                                                                
##
T 192.168.1.1:139 -> 192.168.1.200:42815 [AP]
  ...M.SMBr......................~.....................Z...................N?...zTR                                                                                   
##
T 192.168.1.200:42815 -> 192.168.1.1:139 [AP]
  .....SMBs......................~.........T@..........F............D...+.Pm..0.a\...........'E....Tb.....F........W.O.R.K.G.R.O.U.P........W.O.R.K.G.R.O.U.P...L.i.n.
  u.x. .v.e.r.s.i.o.n. .4...1...1.9.+...C.I.F.S. .V.F.S. .C.l.i.e.n.t. .f.o.r. .L.i.n.u.x...                                                                          
##
T 192.168.1.1:139 -> 192.168.1.200:42815 [AP]
  ...H.SMBs......................~d............Unix.Samba 1.9.16p10.WORKGROUP.                                                                                        
#
T 192.168.1.200:42815 -> 192.168.1.1:139 [AP]
  ...r.SMBu......................~d............G......?....{v....H...a....\.\.1.9.2...1.6.8...1...1.\.s.a.m.b.a...?????.                                              
##
T 192.168.1.1:139 -> 192.168.1.200:42815 [AP]
  .../.SMBu...................'..~d............A:....                                                                                                                 
#
T 192.168.1.200:42815 -> 192.168.1.1:139 [AP]
  ...D.SMB2...................'..~d........................B..............                                                                                            
##
T 192.168.1.1:139 -> 192.168.1.200:42815 [AP]
  ...@.SMB2.....A.............'..~d..................8................                                                                                                
#
T 192.168.1.200:42815 -> 192.168.1.1:139 [AP]
  ...D.SMB2...................'..~d........................B..............                                                                                            
#
T 192.168.1.1:139 -> 192.168.1.200:42815 [AP]
  ...N.SMB2.....A.............'..~d..................8.........@..........S.a.m.b.a.                                                                                  
#
T 192.168.1.200:42815 -> 192.168.1.1:139 [AP]
  ...X.SMBu......................~d............-..\.\.1.9.2...1.6.8...1...1.\.I.P.C.$...?????.                                                                        
#
T 192.168.1.1:139 -> 192.168.1.200:42815 [AP]
  ...#.SMBu......................~d......                                                                                                                             
#
[...]
```

Additional things tried:

- I tried mounting the point as `uid=nobody` and `gid=nogroup`, with same results.
- I run `chmod -R 777` on the mountpoint, didn't make a difference either.
- An interesting thing I found out: If I run `touch` I get a permission denied error, but if I try to run `mkdir` I always get a `mkdir: cannot create directory`blah': File exists` message, no matter what directory name I specify (and of course, it doesn't exist).

**--- EDIT 2 ---**

I also tried running `smbclient -L //192.168.1.1` (without a user) and it asks me for a password that I don't have. If I enter any value as a password, the errors above are shown (`NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`).

But I also tried activating the security in the router panel (setting `Anonymous` to `no`, and setting a username and a password) and here's what I found out:

1) If I just run: `smbclient -L //192.168.1.1`, I'm asked for a password. If I just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I get this output:

```
# smbclient -L //192.168.1.1
Enter root's password: 
Server does not support EXTENDED_SECURITY  but 'client use spnego = yes and 'client ntlmv2 auth = yes'
Anonymous login successful
OS=[楮x慓扭⁡⸱⸹㘱ㅰ0佗䭒則問P] Server=[]

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    samba           Disk      samba share dir
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba Server)
Server does not support EXTENDED_SECURITY  but 'client use spnego = yes and 'client ntlmv2 auth = yes'
Anonymous login successful
OS=[楮x慓扭⁡⸱⸹㘱ㅰ0佗䭒則問P] Server=[]

    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------

    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
    WORKGROUP            SMBSHARE
```

2) If I enter the 'correct' credentials, I get this output:

```
# smbclient -L //192.168.1.1 -U smbshare
Enter smbshare's password: 
Server does not support EXTENDED_SECURITY  but 'client use spnego = yes and 'client ntlmv2 auth = yes'
session setup failed: SUCCESS - 0
```

I'm starting to think this is some kind of bug in the router, but the strange thing is that mounting the samba share works on Windows machines without any issue, where I can also read from and write into the share.

Comment: You could try `mount --verbose -t cifs -o rw,guest,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noperm //192.168.1.1/samba ./asd`.What does `smbclient //192.168.1.1/ -L -U guest%` show?

Comment: @nullterminatedstring Unfortunately, adding the `noperm` option makes no difference. The output of the `smbclient` command is `Connection to -U failed (Error NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME)`

Comment: Sorry, I meant `smbclient -L //192.168.1.1/ -U guest% `.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `forceuid,uid=myuser,forcegid,gid=mygroup` (replacing `myuser` and `mygroup` with your respective ones, obviously) options when mounting?

Comment: @nullterminatedstring Now I get an additional line, but also a similar one to the other: `OS=[楮x慓扭⁡⸱⸹㘱ㅰ0佗䭒則問P] Server=[] | tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME`

Comment: @gmelis yep, still the same. As stated in the question, I tried any `uid` and `gid` from 1 to 10000, but the `forceuid` and `forcegid` options seems to make no difference

Comment: Can you verify there is network traffic between your host and 192.168.1.1 when you're trying to mount the share? It will probably use tcp port 445, so something like `tcpdump -i eth0 -n tcp port 445 and host 192.168.1.1` should work. And another one, can you try to force uid/gid to `nobody/nobody` (or `nogroup`) and see what plays? BTW, throw a `chmod -R 777 ./asd`, just to be sure there's no rights problems involved.

Comment: @gmelis please see the results in the `EDIT 1` section of my question

Comment: Do you see the share when running `smbclient -L //192.168.1.1` as per @nullterminatedstring? Just leave the `-U` argument out. And please add it to the other output above.

Comment: @gmelis please find the output in the `EDIT 2` section.

Comment: Ok, then edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf` (or wherever your `smb.conf` is) and add 2 lines: (a) `client use spnego = no` and (b) `client ntlmv2 auth = no`. Then run `smbclient -L //192.168.1.1` again. It should return something with -hopefully- no errors. BTW, if you get no errors, try mounting again.

Comment: And in the first case, where it asked you for a password you did not have, you could just hit enter. I think it always asks for a password, whether it's required or not.

Comment: @gmelis the problem is that I don't have other access to the router than web access, tried SSHing and Telneting but the root credentials are unknown.

Comment: No, add it to the `smb.conf` of the client. `smbclient` uses `smb.conf` too. In the [global] section.

Comment: @gmelis Ok, added to the client `smb.conf` file, now I can run the `smbclient` command even specifying the user and password and the result is correct, but the mounting permission problem persists

Comment: Yes, `mount.cifs` does not honor `smb.conf`, but you can have a similar result if you toy around with the sec parameter. Like in `mount -t cifs -o guest,sec=ntlm //192.168.1.1/samba ./asd`; look up the `mount.cifs` man page for the full list of `sec` options and try them all one by one. My guess is, one of them will match the server.

Comment: I've always used `mount -t cifs` instead of `mount.cifs` (although the verbose line shows the `mount.cifs` command instead). No change, unfortunately. I've tried any security mechanism (only worked `ntlm` and `none`). Now the news: I found out I can *delete* files, but not create new ones... evidently this is some kind of permission problem but I'm unable to find out what makes it unable to create files (also retried the `uid=nobody,gid=nogroup` options).

Comment: You could try the `nounix` option to make sure that it isn't a unix extension issue.

Comment: Ok, a couple more options to try when mounting: `nosetuid`, `noperm`. You could also try the `vers` parameter, like in `vers=2.0`. I'm pretty sure it's a silly compatibility thing, having a samba server on linux and not being able to mount it under linux. I remember a couple of years ago I had a ZTE, and I could `telnet` with my "admin" password, and then `su` with password `zte`. If it works for you, try to find its `smb.conf` and post a copy of it.

Comment: I agree this must be some kind of compatibility thing. I tried accessing with the default credentials, the problem is that this router is not a brand new one but was modified by my internet company with their own firmware, so I cannot access. I'll keep trying with the hope some combination of parameters will work, if not, I'll connect the HD to some other hardware (a Raspberry Pi, for example) and export it as a samba share.

Comment: I've been having a fight with this today. I think part of the weirdness is that the top level directory is not something you can write into:

; smbclient //192.168.8.20/samba -U samba
Unable to initialize messaging context
Enter WORKGROUP\samba's password: 
Try "help" to get a list of possible commands.
smb: \> put t.sh
NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED opening remote file \t.sh